# Assembly 64bit - movl, movq. Interchanging is okay?

Tags: assembly, 64-bit, x86-64, gnu-assembler, instructions

#### Context:

Learning GAS assembly on 64 bit linux.
Many tutorials are for 32-bit assembly.

Difficult to bushwhack through x86_64 assembly.

#### Question:

When I compile a c program with gcc, I still see some `%eax` and `movl`.

I mostly play with `int32_t`.

But I thought that one *had* to use the 64 bits instructions on `x86_64` (like `rax`,`rbx` and so on).

I don't understand very well. Shouldn't they be `%rax` and `movq` ?
In my assembly programs, I should use `movq`, right ? even for 32 bits integers ?
I am a lost beginner.

Thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use 32 bit registers and instructions in 64 bit mode, just like you can use 16 or 8 bit too. One thing to keep in mind is that 32 bit instructions will automatically zero the top 32 bits of the respective 64 bit registers, while 16 or 8 bit instructions don't:

```
movabsq $0xffffffffffffffff, %rax
movb $0, %al  # rax = 0xffffffffffffff00
movw $0, %ax  # rax = 0xffffffffffff0000
movl $0, %eax # rax = 0x0000000000000000
```

One reason to use 32 bit instructions is that they are shorter machine code.

Comment: Thanks! So gcc may be wrong when using (%rbx) when it only points to a 32 bit value, right ? Should be (%ebx). Should one understand that gcc could be improved in this area ?

Comment: That's a different thing, that is a pointer indirection. The size of the pointer has nothing to do with the size of the item pointed to. `movb (%rbx), %al` is entirely valid and means dereference the 64 bit pointer in `rbx` and fetch a byte from that address into `al`. Pointers in 64 bit code should be 64 bit unless you are certain the top 32 bits are zero.

Comment: Ah yes, my bad ! It is not natural yet for me, but definitely coming :) Thanks Jester